# Javascript Array returns as Array inside array of objects instead of single array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
var fruits=[{"Apple":"1"},{"Apple":"1"}{"Apple":"1"},.......];
```

Here, assume I add more than 100 such objects then in console I see as 
`[[obj1,obj2,...],[obj1,obj2,....]]` depending upon length.
Above scenario happens only if length is more than 100.
It grows in multiples of 100.

Issue :
I am trying to use filter function of jquery.
Once I call `[[obj1,obj2,...],[obj1,obj2,....]].filter(obj){()}`
Here, obj is undefined.

But assume if our array is only like this
`[obj1,obj2,..]` then it works.

`[obj1,obj2,..].filter(obj){()}` // Works Fine

Please help me here. Why array of objects more than 100 does not use filter function also why in console it outputs as `[[obj1,obj2,..],[obj1,obj2,..]]` in more than 100 obj scenarios.

Comment: Can you repro this scenario in a fiddle..?

Comment: The browser console just breaks up large objects. It's still only 1 array as far as javascript is concerned.

Comment: console will only show 100 results. Any more than that will just be shown as `...`

Comment: that is not jQuery's filter function that is the [Array object's filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Also did you mean to write `.filter(function(obj){})` as what you have in your question would throw an error

Comment: @tymeJV http://jsfiddle.net/hc4Lfweg/

Comment: @PatrickEvans I want to filter some objects inside those huge arrays. How to proceed with this ?

Comment: @KrishnanadaM -- And it seems the `.filter` functions works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hc4Lfweg/1/